# Loop through multidimensional array in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

Hey I got this object inside polygons.js:

```
var polygons = [
  {
    "_id" : "12345",
    "geometry" : {
       "coordinates" : [[
           [9.123553, 48.71568],
           [ 9.119548, 48.71526 ]
       ]]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id" : "67890",
    "geometry" : {
       "coordinates" : [[
           [ 9.090445, 48.715736 ],
           [ 9.089583, 48.715687 ]
       ]]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to loop through this array in order to get a *result* like this:

```
[
  { 
    "_id" : "12345",
    "coordinates" : [[
      [9.123553, 48.71568],
      [ 9.119548, 48.71526 ]  
    ]]
  },
  { 
    "_id" : "67890",
    "coordinates" : [[
      [ 9.090445, 48.715736 ],
      [ 9.089583, 48.715687 ]  
    ]]
  }
]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?
Thank you very much in regard!

Comment: Look into `Array.map`.

Answer (score 1):

you can map through the array and make the changes you need

```
formatted_polygons = polygons.map(function(polygon){
    return {
        coordinates : polygon.geometry.coordinates,
        _id : polygon._id
    }
});
```

Comment: when I run the code, it gets me this output:
`{ _id: '12345', coordinates: [ [Array] ] },
  { _id: '67890', coordinates: [ [Array] ] }`

Comment: What functionality of polygon.js are you trying to use ?

Comment: I want to prepare a rest api endpoint that returns the data like this. polygon.js is a json dump I have to use

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify( formatted_polygons ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're just trying to get rid of the "geometry" prop and get the "coordinates" directly?

```
polygons.map(polygon => ({ _id: polygon._id, coordinates: polygon.geometry.coordinates }))
```

Should achieve what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Array.map()`:

```js
var polygons = [ { "_id" : "12345", "geometry" : { "coordinates" : [[ [9.123553, 48.71568], [ 9.119548, 48.71526 ] ]] } }, { "_id" : "67890", "geometry" : { "coordinates" : [[ [ 9.090445, 48.715736 ], [ 9.089583, 48.715687 ] ]] } } ];

let result = polygons.map(({_id,geometry})=>Object.assign({},{_id, coordinates :geometry.coordinates}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, when I run this code cannot see whats inside the coordinates-array. it only logs this:
`[ { _id: '12345', coordinates: [ [Array] ] },
  { _id: '67890', coordinates: [ [Array] ] }]`
I had this issue before, I still can't resolve it

Comment: @LeaHontiveros is there any adjacent to the coordinates, if it is there than please click on the arrow to expand the array. You will be able to see the elements of the array after that. :-) and please mark as accepted if it worked for you.